# bash code to first ping internet and if fails then reboot modem automatically

Tags: bash, expect

I am completely new to bash scripting. Searching and found the  bash code to reboot my modem via telnet. Now I want that  the code first check the internet connectivity then if ping fails run the rest of the script to reboot the modem.
here is the code to reboot modem via telnet (first you have to install expect )

```
 set  timeout 60
    set user  xxxxx
    set  password  xxxxx
    spawn /usr/bin/telnet 192.168.1.1
    expect  "Username:"  {send  "$user\r"}
     expect  "Password:" {send "$password\r"}
    expect "*"  {send "reboot\r"}
    interact
```

Comment: Please add to your question (no comment): What have you searched for, and what did you find? What have you tried, and how did it fail?

Comment: Please take the [tour], read [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: Wow: Telnet in 2021.

Comment: What you have posted isn't bash. It appears to be part of an 'expect' script. I suggest adding that tag if that is what you are using.

Answer (score 1):

Use run command as test condition for ping check:

```
if ping -q -c 1 192.8.8.8; then
    echo "OK"
else
    echo "Fail"
fi
```

Comment: combining two piece of code did not work. I mean place ping condition then putting my code after ELSE

Comment: Could you show full script here?

Comment: 'code' if ping -q -c 1 192.8.8.8; then
    echo "OK"
else
    set  timeout 60
    set user  xxxxx
    set  password  xxxxx
    spawn /usr/bin/telnet 192.168.1.1
    expect  "Username:"  {send  "$user\r"}
     expect  "Password:" {send "$password\r"}
    expect "*"  {send "reboot\r"}
    interact 
fi

Answer (score 0):

You have to using shebang "#!/usr/bin/expect" instead "!/bin/bash" or do like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

SRV_ADDR="example.com"
SRV_PORT="80"

if ping -q -c 1 192.8.8.8; then
    echo "OK"
else
    echo "Fail"
    expect -c "
    spawn telnet ${SRV_ADDR} ${SRV_PORT}
    expect \"Escape character is '^]'.\"
    send \"HEAD http://www.example.com/ HTTP/1.0\n\n\"
    interact
    "
fi
```

In your case it might be:

```
#!/bin/bash

USER="xxxxx"
PASSWORD="xxxxx"

if ping -q -c 1 192.8.8.8; then
    echo "OK"
else
    echo "Fail"

    expect -c "
    spawn telnet 192.168.1.1

    expect \"Username:\"
    send \"${USER}\n\"

    expect \"Password:\"
    send \"${PASSWORD}\n\"

    expect \"reboot\n\"
    interact
    "
fi
```